# Message sending through session isn't showing

Tags: laravel, session, error-handling

In my laravel-7 application I am sending custom message for invalid login in blade through controller. but message is not showing in blade. also tail me if I am doing anything wrong.
in blade

```
<div class="card-body">

                 
                    @if(session()->has('message'))
                        <div class="alert alert-{{session('type')}}">
                            <li>{{session('message')}}</li>
                        </div>
                    @endif



                    <form action="{{route('login')}}" method="post" class="form">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" value="{{old('email')}}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

in auth controller

```
 public function processlogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'email'=>'required|email',
        'password'=>'required|min:6',
    ]);

    $credentials=$request->except(['_token']);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)){
        return redirect()->route('index');
    }
        $this->setErrorMessage('Invalid Credentials.');
        return redirect()->back();

}
```

in controller

```
public function setErrorMessage($message):void
{
    session()->flash($message);
    session()->flash('type','danger');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not naming the flashed variable `message`. You are passing the value of `$message` as the first argument to `flash` which is the name of the key.

```
session()->flash('message', $message);
```